# How can I nest Templates in GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, evaluate

I am cross-training myself from Cold Fusion to Google Apps Scripts. All was going well until I tried to call the createTemplateFromFile function nested within another of the same. Am I trying to do the impossible or can it be done.

My aim is to call:-

htmlhead.html - this just contains static html

bodystart.html - this just contains static html

mainmenu.html - this takes the user context and get/post values to show the menu at the level needed

contentswitcher.html - this takes the get/post value clicked and responds with the data or form html code needed

pagefooter.html - this responds with the page call date/time and the time taken to run

bodyandhtmlend.html - this just contains static html

Each file can contain scriptlets that either run on their own or call functions within something like the Code.gs file, so they need to be evaluated. I can write and test any of these with success. So far, I can evaluate them and output them on their own but I cannot join/concatenate them into one output page. I cannot find anything in the instructions or Q&A that suggest it is even a good/possible idea. Am I looking in the wrong place. A pointer to a different approach would be as welcome as anything.

Many thanks.

Comment: Are your templates html/css only, or you have some JavaScript scripts inside them? Ok, I saw it...

Comment: Maybe show an example of your nested template so we can understand what you are doing and come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy this function into your .gs file:

```
function include(yourHtmlFile) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(yourHtmlFile)
      .getContent();
}
```

... and create single index.html file that will contain templates. Now, you can place your templates into index.html

```
<!-- This goes into <head> -->
<div>
  <?!= include('htmlhead'); ?>
</div>

<!-- This goes into <body> -->
<div>
  <?!= include('bodystart'); ?>
</div>
<div>
  <?!= include('mainmenu'); ?>
</div>
<div>
  <?!= include('contentswitcher'); ?>
</div>
<div>
  <?!= include('pagefooter'); ?>
</div>
<div>
  <?!= include('bodyandhtmlend'); ?>
</div>
```

You can also import some JavaScript code separately, but save it in html file (not in .gs file) with regular  tag.

Comment: Thanks. I now have:-

masterhtmlfile.html - containing

<?!= include2('htmlheader') ?>  spot 1<br><br>
<?!= include2('bodystart') ?>  spot 2<br><br>
<?!= include('showdatetime') ?>  spot 3<br><br>
<?!= include2('showdatetime') ?>  spot 4<br>

The include is in a function file:-

// allows inclusion of complex code and text
function include2(filename) 
{
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
                    .getContent();
}

The output looks like this:-

spot 1
spot 2
Date Time = <?= new Date() ?> spot 3
Date Time = <?= new Date() ?> spot 4

Comment: Is it working, or you have some additional question regarding this topic?

Comment: Oops. Just added the ! but no progress. It is not evaluating the date function within the included showdatetime.html file. Must be getting closer to an answer though. Thanks. (Also I need to learn how to get a formatted paste here to show nicely rather than as I did it above!)

Comment: You have JavaScript code rendered from .html file <?= new Date() ?>

Comment: I will have a re-think and post a supplementary question later. I need to learn more. The new date() bit works in the parent html file but not in the child. I have updated it to <?! = Date() ?> but no progress. Thanks for your pointers. I'll be back later when I can pose a better question.